# Trying to simulate a cannon ball

Tags: iphone, physics

I'm writing a game, and I need to simulate a the path of a cannon ball.
I imagine I would have the initial velocity vector, and a vector for gravity.
Is there a good tutorial on how to do this?
(maybe I need to read some high school text books?)

Comment: Possibly of interest? http://www.amazon.com/Physics-Game-Developers-David-Bourg/dp/0596000065 - it's not great, but it's not a terrible starting point either.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is learn how to use [Cocos2d](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial). You can use a function thats kind of like a timer, it is called 60 times a second by default but you can change this.

What you would do with this is update the x/y position of your sprite (the cannonball image) by a minuscule amount inside this time function, called ccTime.

If your actually looking for the math for the trajectory, [here](http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/) is an amazing tutorial on that

[Here](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/474848) is a question on a forum very similar to yours

Answer (score 2):

You show read the basics of the [**trajectory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory) from where you can extract any equation you need.

If you google '[**cannon ball trajectory**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cannon%20ball#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=cannon%20ball%20trajectory&pbx=1&oq=cannon%20ball%20trajectory&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l8l376280l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=960daeb7459470f9&biw=1280&bih=702)' there is hundreds of tutorials of how to compute the position of an object following a cannon ball trajectory at any given time. [**Here**](http://www.had2know.com/academics/trajectory-parabola-equations-calculator.html) there's an example